# What kind of spider is this half dollar sized brown one with a darker brown body and a lighter brown strip down its back?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification, colorado

I found this spider yesterday running across a sidewalk next to a canal,

[image]

it was bigger than a quarter and I think it was carrying an egg sack.

Does anybody know what kind of spider this is?

Comment: the body kind of reminds me of a wolf spider, but that depends on where you live

Comment: Does look a lot like a wolf spider and they can get pretty big, be curious to see if someone can identify it for certain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely a wolf spider (i.e., family [Lycosidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_spider)). Possibly [***Hogna frondicola***](https://bugguide.net/node/view/1046861) or some closely related species.

[image]

<sup>Source: [Spiderid.com](https://spiderid.com/picture/12910/)</sup>

The white ball is an egg sac. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_spider):

> wolf spiders carry their egg sacs by attaching them to their spinnerets.

You can see similar pictures to your of wolf spiders carrying egg sacs [here](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DALqvQJVYAAfhnG.jpg) and [here](https://natureformysoul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/puzzle8-005.jpg).

[image]

<sup>Source: [Twitter](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DALqvQJVYAAfhnG.jpg)</sup>

[Spiderid.com](https://spiderid.com/spider/lycosidae/hogna/frondicola/) suggests this species has been spotted in Colorado previously:

> *Hogna frondicola* has also been sighted in the following states: Colorado, Maine, Montana.

Comment: Interesting that the pic in the original post and in this answer from @theforestecologist both show what seems to be a 7 legged spider...